# Get two words (numbers) around a certain text in a string

Tags: php

There's a certain contents (from a webpage) where I need to get two numbers of a certain list.
Basically the list goes like:

> ..... 10 from 12....
>
> ..... 1 from 20....
>
> ..... 20 from 100...

and so on. For me, I need to get these numbers surrounding the word "from", so I can perform certain calculations with them later.

I looked into this and tried different ways to perform it with strpos or strstr but nothing worked. Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish something like that?

Comment: Please post the code you already have along with any errors you get, we won't code this from scratch for you.

Comment: I understand but this is like a 5% out of my whole code. The rest is pretty much done. I'm just being stuck at that part. I think the most efficient way is to find the positions of "from" words and than use strpos to clear space around numbers, than use explode to create an array of two numbers exploded with from like explode($str,' from ').

Comment: This is a simple case for regular expressions (php function preg_match)

Comment: Thanks, jspit. I will look into it.

Comment: could you maybe elaborate on how to get the surrounding numbers if using preg_match_all? Because from what I see, it just creates an array : Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => from [1] => from [2] => from [3] => from ) )

Comment: What did you create? `\d` is a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = "..... 10 from 12 etc....

..... 1 from 20....

..... 20 from 100...";

$r = preg_match_all('~(\d+) *from *(\d+)~u',$text,$match, PREG_SET_ORDER);

var_export($match);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '10 from 12',
    1 => '10',
    2 => '12',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '1 from 20',
    1 => '1',
    2 => '20',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '20 from 100',
    1 => '20',
    2 => '100',
  ),
)
```

Explanations:

**\d+** one digit or more

**(\d+)** the sequence in brackets ->  the digits in the result array

***** no, one or more spaces

**from** the word from

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you can do with explode:

```
<?php
/* the text with many different gaps and mess! */ 
$text = "wlfsdjf;sd sdfljsdfk  kfgjdlg d 10 from 200 kflgjdkgdklgsd slfksjd
dfgdf fgdlkjdf d  20 from 30 ldk;lfsd
dflksdjf 40 from 50 dkf;sd sdjfs ";

/* main array */
$array = explode("\n",$text);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);

/* looping and clearing out our values per line */
foreach($array as $k => $line){
    $f = explode(" ",explode(" from ",$line)[0]);
    $f = array_pop($f); 
    $numbers[$k]['first'] = $f;
    $s = explode(" ",explode(" from ",$line)[1]);
    $s = $s[0];
    $numbers[$k]['second'] = $s;
    
}

/* our new array set per line */
print_r($numbers);
```

Will return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => wlfsdjf;sd sdfljsdfk  kfgjdlg d 10 from 200 kflgjdkgdklgsd slfksjd
    [1] => dfgdf fgdlkjdf d  20 from 30 ldk;lfsd
    [2] => dflksdjf 40 from 50 dkf;sd sdjfs 
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first] => 10
            [second] => 200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [first] => 20
            [second] => 30
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [first] => 40
            [second] => 50
        )

)
```

Comment: this also works! Thanks a lot!